# Flutter: When the snapshot is empty the widget disappears

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, snapshot, no-data

I am trying to build a search list, the list is working fine but if the result is empty i need to show no data. I tried the following code but the widget holds for a second and then disappear

```
FutureBuilder(
                    future: getSearchedProducts(widget.searchString),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text('No Data Found.'),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: searchResult.length,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                                  return Card(
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Image.network(searchResult[index].proThumbnail),
                                      title: Text(searchResult[index].proName),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print(searchResult[index].proName);
                                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                          return ProductPage(prodid: searchResult[index].proId);
                                        }));
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  );


                            });
                      }
                    })
```

Can anyone help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just write the code as below and it works.

```
 FutureBuilder(
                    future: getSearchedProducts(widget.searchString),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

                      print('length of list ${searchResult.length}');

                      if (searchResult.length==0) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Text('No data'),
                        );
                      }
                      else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      else {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: searchResult.length,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                                  return Card(
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      leading: Image.network(searchResult[index].proThumbnail),
                                      title: Text(searchResult[index].proName),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print(searchResult[index].proName);
                                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                          return ProductPage(prodid: searchResult[index].proId);
                                        }));
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  );

                            });



                      }
                    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Code in `Else` part before - `return ListView.builder`- add the following code.

```
 ...
 else {
 if (searchResult.length == 0) 
          {
            return Center(child: const Text('No Date'));
          }
 return ListView.builder .....
```

Comment: before`if` condition - try - `print(searchResult.length);` when there is no data does it print 0.